# Change directory and subdirectories and all files permission

Tags: permissions

I would like to change this directory privilage and everything inside from root to www-data, how can I do it? Executed command was `ls -al`

[picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXZLY.png)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to change the owner of a folder recursively.

You can use the following command :

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/your/folder
```

`chown` is the command to CHange OWNer

`-R` is an argument to achieve the command recursively over the content of the folder

`www-data:www-data` is the new user owner followed by the group owner

Comment: the first column (after 69) is set to www-data but the next one is still root

Comment: Ok, I edit the command in the answer, you can try again.